# Angularjs forms not clearing on submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to clear my angularjs form after form submission. I've got the form to submit properly but within my function to submit the form, I've tried clearing the input fields of my form by targeting the `$scope.[name of field here] = '';`

Can someone help me understand why?

Here's my code for the submit function in my controller:

```
$scope.submitOwner = function(){
$scope.firstName = '';
$scope.lastName = '';
$scope.age = '';
$scope.location = '';
$scope.favorite = '';
$scope.numberOfBreeds = '';
$scope.numberOfDogs = '';
Owner.create($scope.owner).success( function(){
console.log('User created!')
});
```

Comment: You are supposed to set that empty on the model, not on the name of the input field. also if you have validation with the name of the form you can set the validity again with `$setValidity()`

Comment: do the inputs make use of ng-model directive?

Comment: @Peege151 yes. So I did make the change that Paulo suggested and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval that worked for me thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made the changes that Paulo suggested in the comments and got it to work! The form was using the 'owner' model and I simply changed the fields to target the ng-model name within the scope and got it to clear successfully! Here's the updated code:

```
  $scope.owner = {};
```

now the form successfully clears. Thanks for clearing that up for me Paulo!